# uploadSuccess: how to render a js.erb response from rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fine-uploader

I am trying to implement a direct to S3 upload system using the fine-uploader script and a rails server.

The problem I am facing is that the endpoint where I post in the event of S3 upload success (i.e. uploadSuccess endpoint) is a controller that renders a rails js.erb template, which supposedly should update the dom. 
The script is caught by the fine-upload script as a successful json response, but the js script is not executed as such.

The relevant code:

images_controller.rb

```
def create
  @image = Image.create!
  set_standard_vars
end
```

create.js.erb (view)

```
alert("This is the view");
$("div#image_name").attr("id", <%= @image.name %>);
```

uploader.js

```
$(function () {
'use strict';

$("div#button").fineUploaderS3({
    debug: true,
    uploaderType: 'basic',
    button: $('div#button'),
    validation: {
      allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
      sizeLimit: 3000000 // 3MB
    },
    objectProperties: {
      key: function(fileId) {
          var filename = $("div#button").fineUploader("getName", fileId);
          return item_picture_bucket + "/" + filename;
      },
      acl: "public-read"
    },
    request: {
        endpoint: "mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
        accessKey: access_key
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: signature_end_point,
        customHeaders: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        }
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: upload_url,
        customHeaders: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        }
    },
  })
});
```

Notice that upload_url is set to be image#create. The create.js.erb template is rendered correctly by rails but the script interprets it as json, as opposed to javascript to be streamed to the browser, and therefore it does not display the alert box.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: We (at Fine Uploader) may not be able to assist much with this, as we don't deal with Ruby or Rails much, but you will increase your chances greatly of an answer from someone more familiar with your stack if you include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for the suggestion. I added the relevant code, please let me know if you fill further information is necessary. It would be good if you guys could add an example in rails (using the js.erb templates which are pretty much standard in rails), especially considering that the product is not free... Thanks anyway.

Comment: That would require on of us to learn rails, which would take a significant amount of time away from feature development, bug fixing, and general support of the library: things that your license fee helps to support.  The server side examples are in a different repo and are MIT licensed.  They are provided as a convenience, but we have detailed documentation on our docs site that explains how to handle Fine Uploader requests in a general sense.

Comment: If it's an endpoint, sounds its more of a systemic issue, rather than one with fine uploader. I'll do my best to answer Ray, don't worry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a reasonable rails solution to this problem.

In the images_controller.rb, instead of rendering the template as javascript, render the template as  text using the render_to_string method and incapsulate it into the json response:

```
def create
  # create! is really to simplify the example, in reality you want to use a background worker to 
  # attach the image to a model and maybe resize it, but this is not the point of the question
  @image = Image.create! 
  set_standard_vars
  render :json => { :success => true, :partial => render_to_string }
end
```

This will send the rendered create.js.erb template back to fineuploader into the json response. I then run the script using the eval JS method and the "on complete" callback:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    $("div#button").fineUploaderS3({
        debug: true,
        uploaderType: 'basic',
        button: $('div#button'),
        validation: {
          allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
          sizeLimit: 3000000 // 3MB
        },
        objectProperties: {
          key: function(fileId) {
              var filename = $("div#button").fineUploader("getName", fileId);
              return item_picture_bucket + "/" + filename;
          },
          acl: "public-read"
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: "anglers-zoo.s3.amazonaws.com",
            accessKey: access_key
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: signature_end_point,
            customHeaders: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            }
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: upload_url,
            customHeaders: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            },
            params: {
              'hash': image_group,
              'position': $('#button_slot').data('imageposition'),
            }
        },
      }).on("submit", function(id, name) {
        $('.destroy_image').hide();
        $('#button').hide();
        $("div#button").parent().find('#throbber').show();
        disable_submit_button();
      }).on("complete", function(event, id, name, responseJSON, xhr){
        jQuery.globalEval(responseJSON.partial);
      });
    });
```

It is still not 100% the rails way, but it is clean and rails-sy enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

Although I've got no experience with `fine uploader`, I'll give you some ideas about Rails, considering the author took the time to reply promptly to you:

---

**respond_to**

```
#app/controllers/images_controller.rb
def create
  @image = Image.create!
  set_standard_vars
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: {success: true} }
  end
end
```

If fine-uploader is [processing the request as JSON](http://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html), perhaps you'd be better to prepare a JSON response? This would allow you to at least handle the response with fine-uploader directly ([rather like how `ajax:success` works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369228/fineuploader-oncomplete-method-not-firing-newbie-require-some-handholding/15369579#15369579)):

```
$("div#button").fineUploaderS3({
    debug: true,
    uploaderType: 'basic',
    button: $('div#button'),
    validation: {
      allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
      sizeLimit: 3000000 // 3MB
    },
    objectProperties: {
      key: function(fileId) {
          var filename = $("div#button").fineUploader("getName", fileId);
          return item_picture_bucket + "/" + filename;
      },
      acl: "public-read"
    },
    request: {
        endpoint: "mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
        accessKey: access_key
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: signature_end_point,
        customHeaders: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        }
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: upload_url,
        customHeaders: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        }
    },
  })
})
.on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
       alert("Success: " + responseJSON.success);
       if (responseJSON.success) {
          alert("success");
       }
});
```

This would need to have the correct JSON returned

Comment: Hi Rich, firstly thanks a lot for the answer. While this answer may work, it is not a rails best practice. I complicated a little bit the example above. You can still work it out with your technique passing additional variables on the json response, nonetheless the preferred rails way is expained here: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3697-server-generated-javascript-responses . While you can argue that this is not a best practice or any workaround that may work is good, to me your approach does not feel right for a rails application (again, from a formal standpoint).

Comment: Also, see here for a rails-style implementation by Ryan Bates of a solution for the same problem using jquery-file-upload. I am wondering if fineuploader can support a similar implementation.

Comment: Thanks for replies - you should look at using `paperclip` with `jquery-file-upload` to handle a totally rails solution. As you're using a bolt-on, you're having to configure for use on Rails, when really you need something that's natively designed for the system

Comment: You will find that switching to jQuery file upload means you will have to handle all of the specifics of uploading to S3 client-side yourself, as jQuery file upload doesn't do any of this for you.  This is not a trivial task, especially if you want to utilize features such as chunking auto-resume, and support for IE9 and older.  If you want to avoid all of that hassle, I would take Rich's original suggestion/answer if it works.

Comment: If you use JQuery with Rails, you'll just have to pass the data to Rails (Paperclip) and that will handle the upload to S3. Only problem is you'll have to go through ActiveRecord (create a db entry), but from your code, it looks like you're doing that already. [Paperclip natively supports S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)

Comment: It looks like this will require sending the files to an intermediate server first, which is something that Fine Uploader S3 avoids completely.