# Dynamically created Fineuploader and Serializing Form Data (Wire Format for Model Binding)

Tags: jquery, file-upload, model-binding, fine-uploader

I'm working with the jquery wrapper for Fineuploader (v5.3) within an MVC C# app.

My controller retrieves a bunch of metadata on how my view needs to look ('n' number of text fields, and 'n' number of upload controls), and it's passed to the view. BAM.  Creating these dynamic upload controls is already solved here:  [Dynamic Multiple Upload Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025238/fineuploader-multiple-instances-and-dynamic-naming).  My current issue is slightly different in that I need the upload and form posting to work together in one shot (no intermediate place to save files).  In addition, seeing I don't know what's going to be passed from the view to the controller, I'm utilizing dictionary collections to keep track of both important Id information and their values.  Serializing the text collection from the view to the controller is working just fine (i.e fieldName[0].property = value. See Hanselman's Wire Format For Model Binding [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) for more details).

**So, what's my actual problem?**  Getting this wire format serializing to work for the uploader's file(s), along with having it post correctly with the form.

So, you now now the high level issues, let me start explaining in more detail.

**Here's the Controller Model:**
[image]

Here's the **form post without any upload info**:  You can see the Wire Format in action here.  Serializes nicely.
[image]

Here I dynamically create a hidden html field, add a key and value.  It **serializes just fine into the UserText dictionary property**.  See that here:

[image]

Here's my **FineUploader jQuery code**.  I'm utilizing Razor to add a counter to the instance so each is unique.

```
$('#files-upload@(counter)').fineUploader({
    debug: false,
    autoUpload: false,
    template: 'qq-template-@(counter)',     
    form: {
        element : '@formId'
    },
    validation: {
        acceptFiles: ['image/*', 'application/acrobat', 'application/x-pdf', 'text/pdf', 'text/x-pdf'],
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'pdf', 'tif', 'tiff'],
        sizeLimit: 1024 * 1024 * 9,
        stopOnFirstInvalidFile: false
    },
    multiple: false
}).on('submitted', function (event, id, filename) {     
    alert('submitted from ' + @counter);
}).on('complete', function (event, id, filename, responseJSON) {
    var element = $("li[qq-file-id=" + id + "] .qq-upload-status-text");      
    element.html("Success");
    alert('complete individual from ' + @counter);
}).on('allComplete', function (succeeded, failed) {       
    alert('ALL complete from ' + @counter);
}).on('error', function (event, id, name, errorReason, xhr) {       
    alert('Error[@(counter)]: ' + errorReason);
});
```

After dynamically adding 2 upload controls to my form and posting it:

```
$('#files-upload0').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');

$('#files-upload1').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');

$('#@formId').submit();
```

I see **this form data when I submit with the upload controls**: [image].

I've looked at the setForm documentation, though I'm not sure how to use it: [setForm](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setForm) and I'm wondering if I still require the onComplete events, etc.

Also, if using the Wire Format idea for the serialized collection, where would I change the property names for the incoming files?  For example, I think I'd need to have a qqfile[0].HttpPostedFile, qqfile[0].ContentLength, qqfile[0].InputStream, etc.  so the serializer can associate and assign the properties.  With what's currently posted only the 2nd file upload details (llama.jpg) seems to come across the wire.  Does what I'm trying to explain make sense, or can you think of an easier way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The `setForm` API method allows you to attach Fine Uploader to a specific `<form>` element. This is useful for registering a form that did not exist when the Fine Uploader instances was created, or if your target form has changed.

For example:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({});
uploader.setForm(document.querySelector('form'))
```

More details can be found on the [form feature page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/forms.html) on the documentation site.

Comment: Can you upload files from multiple upload controls within a single form post?  It seems that my request endpoint is hit multiple times (equal to the number of upload controls), and each time also includes the other form data.  Problem is, I don't have everything at once.  Can this be done?

Comment: It just seems that whether you have a single upload control or multiple upload controls, the upload method is hit once for each file that is uploaded.  There's no collection of all of them, regardless of how many, uploading at once.  Am I wrong?